# Prove: Partitions and refinements

Tags: integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

Problem: Let $ R $ be the set of partitions of a real interval. Then for all elements in $ R $, every pair of elements has an upper bound.

I am having trouble structuring the proof; and intuitively understanding why every pair of elements has an upper bound.

Comment: let say you have two (simple) partitions {$A$,$A^c$} and {$B$,$B^c$} of your real interval I, then you can cut I in four : $A\cap B^c, A^c \cap B, A^c\cap B^c$and $A\cap B$. And this is a refinement of both {$A$,$A^c$} and {$B$,$B^c$}. You can apply the same idea with any partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the interval be $[a,b]$. A partition $X$ of $[a,b]$ is a finite sequence $X=\langle x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ of points of $[a,b]$ such that $x_0=a$, $x_n=b$, and $x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n$. A partition $Y=\langle y_0,\ldots,y_m\rangle$ refines $X$ if and only if $\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}\subseteq\{y_0,\ldots,y_m\}$: every partition point of $X$ is a partition point of $Y$ or, equivalently, each interval of $Y$ is contained in an interval of $X$.

For reflexivity, you need only show that each partition of the interval is a refinement of itself; that’s completely trivial.

For transitivity you must show that if $Y$ refines $X$, and $Z$ refines $Y$, then $Z$ refines $X$; that also is a very straightforward application of the definition of *refines*.

Suppose that $X=\langle x_0,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ and $Y=\langle y_0,\ldots,y_m\rangle$ are partitions of $[a,b]$; you want a partition $Z=\langle z_0,\ldots,z_r\rangle$ that refines both $X$ and $Y$ and has the further property that if $W$ refines $X$ and $Y$, then $W$ refines $Z$. In other words, you want $Z$ to be the coarsest possible common refinement of $X$ and $Y$.

- What partition points does $Z$ absolutely have to include in order to refine in order to refine both $X$ and $Y$?
- Does $Z$ have to include any partitions points beyond that bare minimum?

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. In the last paragraph, did you mean to say $ Z $ refines $ W $? So $ Z $ absolutely has to include all partition points of both $ X $ and $ Y $; does it have to include any more than that?

Comment: @kay: No, $W$ refines $Z$. You want $Z$ to be the least upper bound of $X$ and $Y$, so you want $X<Z$, $Y<Z$, and $Z<W$ whenever $X<W$ and $Y<W$. \\ Yes, $Z$ must include every partition point of $X$ and $Y$. If you include other points, it will still be an upper bound for $X$ and $Y$; will it be the **least** upper bound?

Comment: I understand now; but what is the significance of it being the least upper bound? Don't we just need that $ Z $ is an upper bound?

Comment: @kay: You’re right: as the problem is stated, any upper bound will serve. I unconsciously added the extra condition — I can’t see the question and my answer simultaneously! — because there are times when you do want a least upper bound. In any case it’s the easiest upper bound to define concretely from $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Since partitions are just finite sets of reals containing endpoints ,then consider a following situation.

Namely one partition $X$ is refinement of other  partition $Y$ iff $Y \subseteq X$.

Then we have a situation that for relation $<$ as defined above ,following holds:

$$X<Y \Leftarrow \Rightarrow X \subseteq Y$$

The inclusion relation is both reflexive and transitive,thus so must be your defined relation.

As for upper bounds,if $X$ and  $Y$ are partitions then their union is their upper bound,since union of finite sets is finite,and their union refines both of them.

Comment: If partitions were defined as sequences, rather than sets, one could consider the function $\operatorname{im}: \{partitions\} \to \{sets\}$, $X \mapsto \text{image of } X$, then show (easily) that $X \leqslant Y$ if and only if $\operatorname{im} X \subseteq \operatorname{im} Y$, and infer properties of the relation $\leqslant$ on partitions from the evident properties of $\subseteq$ on sets.

Comment: Thanks. If they are equal, wouldn't the union still refine the partition because every partition is a refinement of itself?

Comment: Good point,I overlooked that,I will edit my post